# Кастомные поля в WooCommerce WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Задача состоит в том чтобы добавить дополнительные поля в товары категории и на главную страницу.

Я через плагин advanced custom fields смог добавить поля в товары и категории при этом в товарах получилось вывести а вот в категориях не получилось.

У меня вопрос: как вывести эти поля для категорий?

Comment: На странице редактирования категории вукомерс же как-то повилось поле, как получить его во фронтэнде, уже на всех шаблонах перепробовал http://joxi.ru/RmzyMPf0d1XQrO

Comment: категорию оторажает темплейт taxonomy-product_cat.php вот в нем и должно отрабатывать поле но почему-то ничего не выводит the_field();

Comment: как получить метаполя таксономии ?